# 3D Touch - Peek and Pop - should return UIViewController but video is not ready yet

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, return, grand-central-dispatch

In the function

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {   
   let peekViewController = UIViewController()
   if videosActive == true {
      // DO VIDEO PROCESSING TO GET VIDEO URL
      // CREATE AVLPLAYER WITH URL
      // ADD AVPLAYERLAYER TO PEEKVIEWCONTROLLER.LAYER
      avPlayer.play()
   }    
   return peekViewController
}
```

I want to be able to peek on videos as in Instagram and see them. However, this function needs to return a UIViewController, so I have to have some return UIViewController outside any if statement. What should I do? In 30% of the times I do it, the videos plays perfectly in the PeekViewController, but 70% of the time there is no video at all. Print statements showed me that the `return peekViewController` is being called before `avPlayer.play()` so that 70% of the time the video is not ready/loaded to be displayed. Is there a way to only call `return peekViewController` after video is ready? I tried to use GCD but got in the fundamental problem of the function needing to return something. Could you guys please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The method signature allows an optional return, so you can return `nil` if there is no video

Comment: I know but if replace the last line with return nil there will never be a video being displayed at all. Is there a way I could only call the last line after I am sure the video is loaded?

Comment: What is your if statement checking for then?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code. Firstly, you should not create `peekViewController` that way. It should be a normal VC in your storyboard, and then all the code to set up the video should be in the subclass for that VC. You then create `peekViewController` along the following lines:

```
let peekViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PeekViewController") as? PeekViewController
```

Then pass the asset to the VC, for it to do all the video setup:

```
peekViewController.asset = pictureAssets[hltPicIndexPath.row] as! PHAsset
    // or
peekViewController.asset = videoAssets[hltVideoIndexPath.row] as! PHAsset
```

Also, `requestAVAssetForVideo` runs in the background and returns immediately. Therefore "testing this time option" will invariably occur before `player.play()`, but this shouldn't be a problem.